# Delete the price from whole site and from product magento 2

Tags: magento2

In my website i want to insert product without price and so i don't want to see this attribute none in FO none on BO so how to proceed any help please ?? another question  please: i want to buy products on wholesales so that if a client want to buy some book he should know that when he choose to buy 300 book the box can contain 240 piece so he should choose the quantity 2 (2box) so please help me i am really stuck in this part please it's an emergency and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The di.xml file is the one below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration" type="ZEndertech\BundleExtended\Helper\Catalog\Product\Configuration"/>
</config>
```

ran php bin/magento setup:upgrade command, reloaded the page.

Comment: where is the di.xml ??

Comment: Initial (app/etc/di.xml)
Global (<moduleDir>/etc/di.xml)
Area-specific (<moduleDir>/etc/<area>/di.xml)

Comment: thanks for your replay but i did not understand anything and which part of my question this replay

Comment: give me more information please